# Entropy of a factorised joint distribution

Tags: entropy, information-theory, mutual-information, maximum-entropy

Suppose I have three discrete random variables $X, Y$ and $Z$.

Their joint distribution factorises as so:

$$
P(X,Y,Z) = P(X)P(Y)P(Z)
$$
i.e. they are fully independent variables.

Now suppose I want to calculate the entropy of the joint (starting from the left), plugging this into the Shannon entropy gives

$$
H(X,Y,Z) = \sum_x \sum_y \sum_z P(X,Y,Z) \log P(X,Y,Z)
$$
which, because of independence, we can simplify to:
$$
H(X,Y,Z) = \sum_x \sum_y \sum_z P(X)P(Y)P(Z) \log P(X)P(Y)P(Z).
$$
Apart from breaking apart the $\log$ in the above expression, can this be simplified further when one explicitly knows that the random variables are independent? Is there some way one can operate on the individual factors (of the first equation) to simplify this entropy calculation? **I.e. if the variables are independent can you add the entropies together to get the joint entropy?**

Comment: Answered here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_entropy#Less_than_or_equal_to_the_sum_of_individual_entropies

Comment: And "behind the scenes" for the above link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy

Comment: Ah yes, there we go, if they are independent then the mutual information between them will be zero, and hence we can just add up their individual entropies.